# Jackson ContextualDeserializer cannot get the contextualType when decoding a generic Kotlin class

Tags: kotlin, generics, jackson

I have a custom implementation of a `JsonDeserializer` which implements a `ContextualDeserializer` in order to deserialize a generic class. Everything works fine until the generic class itself has a property which is also a generic class.

For demo purposes, I simplified the code to the minimum

My class is

```kotlin
data class MyObject<out Content>(
    val content: Content
)
```

Deserializing `MyObject<String>` works:

```json
{
  "content": "Hello"
}
```

but deserializing `MyObject<MyObject<String>>>` does not:

```json
{
  "content": {
    "content": "Hello"
  }
}
```

The custom deserializer is the following. The issue seems to be that `contextualType.containedType` is returning null.

I believe this issue is in the line

```kotlin
val content = ctxt.readTreeAsValue(contentNode, contentType!!.rawClass)
```

because the `.rawClass` does not have any additional information about the generic type. So the content is deserialized as just `MyObject` instead of `MyObject<String>`.

```kotlin
class MyObjectDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<MyObject<*>?>(), ContextualDeserializer {
    private var contentType: JavaType? = null

    override fun createContextual(ctxt: DeserializationContext?, property: BeanProperty?): JsonDeserializer<*> {
        contentType = if (property == null)
            ctxt!!.contextualType.containedType(0)
        else
            property.type.containedType(0)

        if (contentType != null) {
            println("${ctxt!!.contextualType} has contained type $contentType")
        } else {
            // Here is where the issue occurs
            println("${ctxt!!.contextualType} does not have any contained types")
        }
        return this
    }

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext): MyObject<*> {
        val codec = p?.codec ?: throw NullPointerException()
        val node = codec.readTree<JsonNode>(p)
        val contentNode = node.get("content")
        val content = ctxt.readTreeAsValue(contentNode, contentType!!.rawClass)
        return MyObject(content)
    }
}
```

and I register the deserialzers like so

```
fun ObjectMapper.registerMyDeserializers(): ObjectMapper {
    val module = SimpleModule().also {
        it.addDeserializer(MyObject::class.java, MyObjectDeserializer())
    }
    return this.registerModule(module)
}
```

The unit test the demonstrates the issue is the follow. The first test works fine, the second fails.

```kotlin
class ResponseParsingTests {
    private val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper().registerMyDeserializers()

    @Test
    fun `parses String as content`() {
        val json = """
        {
          "content": "Hello"
        }
        """.trimIndent()

        val result = objectMapper.readValue<MyObject<String>>(json)
        assertEquals("Hello", result.content)
    }

    @Test
    fun `parses MyObject as content`() {
        val json = """
        {
          "content": {
            "content": "Hello"
           }
        }
        """.trimIndent()

        val result = objectMapper.readValue<MyObject<MyObject<String>>>(json)
        assertEquals("Hello", result.content.content)
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm aware the this example class does not require any custom deserialzer at all. However my real use case is a bit more complex and I need to use a custom deserializer because I'm publishing my code as part of a library which suppoorts multiple serialization frameworks (gson, jackson, kotlinx). So the serialization cannot be part of my actual class but rather in a separate one.